# "Failed to load resource" and other errors running and modifying firebase firestore app tutorial

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm following the Firebase Firestore tutorial located at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart to learn how to use the Firestore No- SQL document store.

I built the simple app using the `npx webpack –watch` command so I could refresh the page and get updated changes on the fly. Webpack puts the main.js or bundle.js file in the dist folder of the project root.

I have made several changes to the 'index.html' script tag in vain to get the app working.

If I use `<script src=”dist/main.js”></script>`  or  `<script src=”main.js”></script>` I get the following:[image: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a staus of 404 (Not Found)]

If I use:
`<script src=”index.js”></script>` I get the following error:
[image: Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module.]

So I used the `<script type=module` attribute.

If I use:  `<script type=module src="index.js"></script>`  I get the following:

[image: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "firebase/app". Relative reference must start with either "/", "./" or "../".]

So I thought I would put a "/" and a "./" in front of `index.js`

If I use:  `<script type=module src="/index.js"></script>` or `<script type=module src="./index.js"></script>`

I get the same error as above: [image: localhost/:1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "firebase/app". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".]

What's going on here?

Here is the file structure:

```
Project Root
    >dist
        -main.js
    >node_modules
    >src
        -index.html
        -index.js
    >package.json
    >package-lock.json
    >webpack.config.js
```

Here are the key files:
**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>My Simple Cafe</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>
    <h2>Hello Firestore!</h2>
</p>
<script type=module src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
     // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
        import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
        import { getFirestore, doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
        import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics"
        // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries
        
        // Your web app's Firebase configuration
        // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
        const firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: <apiKey>
            authDomain: <authDomain>
            databaseURL: <databaseURL>
            projectId: <projectId>
            storageBucket: <storageBucket>
            messagingSenderId: <messagingSenderId>
            appId: <appId>
        };
        
        // Initialize Firebase
        const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
        
        const firestore = getFirestore();
        
        const specialOfTheDay = doc(firestore, 'dailySpecial/2021-09-14')
        function writeDailySpecial(){
            const docData = {
                description: 'A delicious vanilla latte',
                price: 3.99,
                milk: 'Whole',
                vegan: false,
            };
            setDoc(specialOfTheDay, docData)
        }
        console.log("Hello , Firestore!")
        writeDailySpecial();
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
    const path = require('path');

    module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: '/src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'main.js',
    }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^9.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "serve": "^13.0.2",
    "webpack": "5.52.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.2"
  },
  "name": "simplecafe",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Tutorial from https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo\"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "Todd Kerpelman",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, how about you try '../dist/main.js', and let me know if it works?

Comment: Hi, thanks.  I'm in the process of refactoring the app as a React app. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, please let me know if it works.

Comment: @Zeenath S N I will.  I will post the refactored code here.  I think it may help someone.